# In ASP.NET MVC4 using javascript

Tags: .net

When the button is clicked the date and time should store into the database using mvc4 and javascript.

I got the date but this should be stored in database
can you help me? This is my view page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var date = new Date();
    alert(date);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="click" name="Click" onclick="myclick();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a new action within a controller in MVC and write a function that would parse through the date and store it in the database.

After that, the URL for your action would need to be called using AJAX. AJAX is a way of a client side technology (such as JavaScript) connecting with back end technology (such as .NET). You can use jQuery's AJAX functions and there is more information about it here: -
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score -2):

Dear Sankeats,
              From Javascript Function you have to call Post method which is inside your Conrtoller.In Controller you have to do your logic to store your field in database.

Hope it will help you.